# Has the arithmetic mean of the Leibniz series been used for computing $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-history, pi

I'm sure this was asked before, but I wasn't able to find the answer.

If we have an alternating series with slow convergence, can't we just use the arithmetic mean to get a much better approximation to the limit?

For example, every source says that Leibniz series for $\pi$ is a very bad way to compute it, but if we just divide the last term of a partial sum by $2$, which is equivalent to taking the arithmetic mean of consecutive partial sums, we get a faster convergence.

> Have Leibniz or other researchers at the time used this method for getting a good approximation to $\pi$?

Here's the partial sums of Leibniz series (even in orange and odd in green), their arithmetic mean (red) and the exact value of $\pi/4$ (blue) plotted together:

[image]

Another example: the alternating series for $\log 2$:

[image]

---

There's a similar question, but it's not about history, just about the method itself: [Pi series that converges arbitrarily fast.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2549979/269624). $$ $$ Also note, that I'm not interested in more advanced methods of series acceleration, but in whether this (extremely simple and obvious one) been used at the time

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366301/72031) is a very nice approach to deal with Leibniz series.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, that is quite impressive, thank you